# NEAR SC Challenge - simple AS error "Not enough non-option arguments: got 1, need at least 2" (Powershell n VSCode)

Tags: nearprotocol

Contract built and dev-deployed / but running modified method or added method fails /

helloWorld() wit no parms should display/view modified return string - DOES NOT!

Added 2nd method / also fails (whatsYourName())

Comment: I switched from Powershell + vscode to WSL2,ubuntu + vscode and and NOW NOT having these errors - FYI

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn the basics of calling contracts on NEAR at your own pace would be to go through this workshop: https://github.com/near-examples/workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts

We discussed the missing piece argument above -- it was an environment variable not being addressed properly in a Windows shell -- something about `$CONTRACT` vs. `%CONTRACT%` maybe